# What is the leading for different font sizes?

Tags: memoir, fontsize

I'm doing some picky adjustments to vertical space, so as to make sure lines of text stay in alignment after various skips in vertical space (e.g. I'm adjusting any vertical skips to be multiples of normal text leading). The only problem is, I haven't messed with the default leading values, so I don't know what they are. I can find the value of the leading for normal text with this `\message{Leading: \the\onelineskip}`. How can I find the leading of other sizes (i.e. `\tiny`, `\Large`, `\huge`, etc.)? I'm using the memoir class, and p.46 of the documentation gives me the point size of different font sizes, but not the leading (probably because they are often changed and dependent on font).

Specific details that may be of use:

1. I'm using the memoir class.
2. My `\normalsize` size is `11pt`.
3. The leading of `\normalsize` font is `13.6pt`. This number comes from the above `\message`.
4. I'm using the font BaskervilleF.

TL;DR: How can I find the leading of different font sizes?

Comment: It is listed in `mem11.clo`

Comment: @daleif Where can I find that file?

Comment: The location can be found via `kpsewhich mem11.clo` in a terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write to the document, not a message to the terminal, and use `\baselineskip`.

```
% memfontsprob.tex  SE 600981
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\message{Leading: normalsize \the\onelineskip} % to terminal

The normalsize leading is \the\baselineskip  % to document

\Huge The Huge leading is \the\baselineskip\par

\end{document}
```

[image]